MySQL Server keeps hitting 100% CPU
My server has 800+ days uptime, but ever since a couple weeks the MySQL server keeps hitting 100% CPU and I have to restart the mysqld service.
Where do I start to find out where this issue is coming from? As all the sites on my server keep freezing until I restart. I don't want to keep restarting the service every time. Sometimes it is after a couple minutes, sometimes a couple hours, sometimes a couple days.
Nothing changed really. I only once updated the my.cnf file for the default character set and restarted recently, but I don't believe this is linked in any way.
--- Server details ---
Debian 10 Buster
MySQL Version: 14.14
Average users: 150 - 200 per day
vCPU's: 4
RAM: 4GB
my.cnf
No slow queries shown so far.
[mysqld]
collation_server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
character_set_server = utf8mb4
sql-mode="NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/slow_queries.log
log_queries_not_using_indexes = 'OFF'
long_query_time = 5


does your slow query log file show any suspicious queries that take long? Someone doing a huge join, or something recursive-alike in a stored procedure? What does dmesg tell you – maybe something wrong with accessing stored data? You could probably also throw perf top -a at the problem and figure out what your CPU does while it's so busy.

Also, a single server with 4 GB RAM might be sufficient, but if you have "multiple sites" depending on it, maybe a (simple, i.e., single-primary) MySQL InnoDB cluster is the way to go (and seriously, 4GB for something you need MySQL for? Very little.)? And, I'm terribly sorry, but saying "my server has 800+ days uptime", when you just restarted the service, that's not saying much for your reliability. It suggests that you might occasionally upgrade your systems than to strive for uptime. With a cluster, you might be able to just upgrade individual backing servers, with no service downtime.

@MarcusMüller For now, I solved the issue by increasing the VPS with 2 vCPU's (from 2 to 4). Obviously, I am still curious as to what is happening. Slow query log got me a couple of hints of queries I could simply disable / remove. As for dmesg and perf top -a, what do you use them for exactly? I do use htop to track CPU / RAM usage. And do you mean to say 4GB is not much for using MySQL? Or the opposite? Sorry if I didn't understand you correctly. Thank you for your help!

dmesg would contain things like storage failures. So, check for errors. perf top -a shows you that when regularly sampling what the CPU currently does, in which functions it is the most often. 4GB is silly little for a database machine. After all, you're probably using MySQL instead of an in-process database because it makes sense to live with the overhead of cross-process communication, synchronization and data (de)serialization, because the queries are complicated enough or the data so large that doing it on a dedicated machine compensates these downsides.
